# Using jQuery to horizontally center images with different widths in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="photos">
 <div id="photos_cycle">
   <img id="photo" src="{{ asset('bundles/tcheetenweb/images/photos/female_tennis_player.jpg') }}" />
   <img id="photo" src="{{ asset('bundles/tcheetenweb/images/photos/foto_1.jpg') }}" />
   <img id="photo" src="{{ asset('bundles/tcheetenweb/images/photos/foto_2.jpg') }}" />
   <img id="photo" src="{{ asset('bundles/tcheetenweb/images/photos/foto_3.jpg') }}" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Which has an element photos_cycle with the different images, all with the same ID, here is where the problem comes in.

I use the following javascript to cycle the images:

```
$('#photos_cycle').cycle({
 fx: 'fade',
 timeout: 8000,                    
 speed: 0
});
```

It cycles the image after 8 seconds, nothing exciting here.

Now I want to center my images depending on their width I determine how the width of the photos_cycle should be so that I can center it:

```
setInterval(function () {
 $("#photos_cycle img").each(function() {
  imageWidth = this.clientWidth;                        
  if (imageWidth > 0) {
   $("#photos_cycle").css('width', imageWidth);                  
  });                                
}, 10);
```

The only problem with this is that it works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE...
The biggest problem I find in this is that I'm having a problem identifying what image size I'm checking, because they all have the same id.

I hope someone can help me with this.

A live example of it can be found at http://test.tc.heeten.nl/, look at the block on the bottom right.

Edit:

I don't want to uniquely define the ID's because later I want to automatically add the images to the photos_cycle div, using some PHP code.

This is the css I use for the divs:

```
#photos {
    background-color: #8ab7e2;
    width: 340px;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;

    top: 60px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #000;
}

#photos_cycle { 
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#photos_cycle img {
    display: block;

    height: 200px;

    margin-top: 18px;

    position: position:absolute;
    left:50%;

    border: 2px solid #000;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This question isn't clear. Why do you have to set the image widths?

Comment: Why the downvote for him?  He showed his code and expressed his question well.  We shouldn't be voting down a question simply because he has a problem with his code.

Comment: Thanks for your support, if the question is not clear, please clarify what isn't clear so I can add it to the question.
Now my posts seems to have a -1, will it still be seen?

Answer (score 2):

*Your elements should not have the same ID. ID must be unique.*

The problem can actually be solved using CSS. Just use the `text-align: center;` style to center the image within the div.

```
#photos_cycle { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: This will only work if the image is smaller or with the same width as the div.

Answer (score 0):

This is how center images through jQuery:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #your_image_id {
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:100px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var width = $("#your_image_id").width();

        var margin = width/2;

        $("#your_image_id").css("margin-left","-"+margin);
    });
</script>
```

what this does is, it makes 50% margin from left side of the screen and move the image to left with width / 2 pixels, which is the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small jQuery plugin to achieve this cross-browser:

http://boxlight.github.com/bl-jquery-image-center